# minimize the number of interset points extracted by SURF

Tags: surf, object-detection

I have a question about feartures extracted by surf ,
I want to use it for object detection purpose
I'm getting a large number of interset points for every different image and I want a specific number of features to pass it to the machine learning .
how can I minimize this number of interset points ?

Thanks ...... :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to increase the minHessian threshold value?